# Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<UIAccessibilityCustomAction, bool>

Tags: c#, ios, asynchronous, xamarin, task

Getting error:

Error CS4010: Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task, none of which are convertible to 'Func

```
UIAccessibilityCustomAction someAccessibilityAction = new
                UIAccessibilityCustomAction(
                SwipeActionMarkTextValue("Accessibility Text", false),
                            async (UIAccessibilityCustomAction arg) =>{

                                 await TestAsyncMethod();
                                return true;
                            });


    private async Task<bool> TestAsyncMethod()
    {
         await Task.Delay(5000);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: And what don't you understand about the error?  It's rather explicit in what it's saying is wrong.

Comment: I have no idea what to change it too...

Comment: @jimmyneutron You can not treat a Func<T, X> as asynchronous, it needs to be a synchronous behavior, your TestAsyncMethod would need to return `bool`

Comment: its returning true...

Comment: @jimmyneutron No, it's returning a `Task<bool>` that will have a true result *5 seconds later*.  Big difference.

Comment: what do I need to change this to?

Answer (score 2):

### Your async method doesn't return a bool. It returns a Task<bool>.

Remember that async is (kindof) syntactic sugar for ContinueWith. Your syntax is perfect but it helps to illustrate my point if I rewrite it as:

```
(UIAccessibilityCustomAction arg) => TestAsyncMethod().ContinueWith(b => true)
```

### Possible solutions

I am not familiar with Xamarin.iOS, and it also depends on the task you want to achieve but here are some general solutions:

1. Use an API that accepts an async callback if there is one.
2. Make your work synchronous.
3. Wait (block) on your work item:

   ```
   /*NO ASYNC HERE*/ (UIAccessibilityCustomAction arg) =>{
       TestAsyncMethod().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
           return true;
       })
   ```

   Depending on your situation [this might cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) though.
4. Make your worker "fire and forget" (async void) and immediately return true after kicking it off.

   ```
   UIAccessibilityCustomAction someAccessibilityAction = new UIAccessibilityCustomAction(
       SwipeActionMarkTextValue("Accessibility Text", false),
       (UIAccessibilityCustomAction arg) => {
           TestAsyncMethod();
           return true;
       });
   private async void TestAsyncMethod()
   {
       await Task.Delay(5000);
   }
   ```

Comment: I just want to call the async method, it doesn't have to return anything fancy.

Comment: Try options 3 or 4 then